# findstr DOS Command's multiple string "A B" or "B A" argument

Tags: command-line

I am using

findstr /c:"A B" *.txt

"A" and "B" are single words (names of two team members) in a text
file, like "Miller Smith" etc.
But now we encountered that sometimes we have the sequence "B A" as
in the example above, it is written as: "Smith Miller".

Any solution for 'findstr' to find "Smith Miller" OR "Miller Smith" 
at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

`/c` could be specified more than once:

```
findstr /c:"A B" /c:"B A" *.txt
```